# .htaccess to make a subfolder the main folder for primary domain, but getting redundant redirects when URL is typed directly into browser

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns, subdirectory

**Problem:**

I'm using .htaccess to make a subfolder the main folder for my primary domain.
Everything seems to be working fine, except I noticed that when I type a URL directly, such as "primarydomain.com/blog/", 
it redirects to "http://primarydomain.com/primarydomain.com/blog/".

**Details:**

Currently I have multiple domains under the same webhosting account.
This webhost originally organized my files as:

- public_html/ for all the webfiles for my primary domain name (primarydomain.com)
- public_html/domain2.com/ for all the webfiles for one of my other domains
- public_html/domain3.com/ for all the webfiles for another one of my domains

Using .htaccess and RewriteRule, I've been able to re-organize my files for peace of mind into:

- public_html/primarydomain.com/
- public_html/domain2.com/
- public_html/domain3.com/

...with said .htaccess file in that root directory:

- public_html/.htaccess

This .htaccess file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?primarydomain.com$

# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/primarydomain.com/

# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /primarydomain.com/$1

# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?primarydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ primarydomain.com/ [L]

# this last line I commented out because it was causing all the links (direct links) to all my files to hit 404 errors
# I have included this line as a reference because it was in the original tutorial I used
# RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)?$ primarydomain.com/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

The tutorial I used:
http://support.lunarpages.com/knowledge_bases/article/549
(I don't use lunarpages, but the structure is the same)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any hints/tips would be most appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Most of the rules in your .htaccess file are incorrect, and it is difficult to tell your intent. If you can state your intent for each, it would be easier to help you

Comment: @UlrichPalha The entire piece of code is to make the subfolder public_html/primarydomain.com/ my main folder for that primary domain.  It also follows the tutorial which I've linked to at the bottom.  If any of the htaccess rules are incorrect, please explain.

Comment: Is this happening when you type "primarydomain.com/blog" in your address bar (note the missing trailing slash) or is it happening with the trailing slash as well? I don't see anything in your rules that redirects the browser.

Comment: @JonLin I just noticed that actually - yes, the error only occurs when I do not include that last trailing slash.  When I type "primarydomain.com/blog/" though, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to move the physical directory where your domain is located to the `primarydomain.com` folder, the rules below should work. I left out the last section of your original rules as I was not sure what they were meant to do.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if the host is on primarydomain.com or www.primarydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?primarydomain\.com$ [NC]
#and URI does not already start with /primarydomain.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/primarydomain.com/ [NC]
# And not for an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#then rewrite all requests that to primarydomain.com/ folder
RewriteRule (.*) primarydomain.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it didn't change anything.  I did notice another oddity though: when I type "primarydomain.com/path/" the page loads as expected; when I type "primarydomain.com/path" (WITHOUT the extra forwardslash at the end) it redirects to "primarydomain.com/primarydomain.com/path/".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an issue with the missing slash, you could try turning `DirectorySlash Off`, mod_dir's automatic redirect when missing a trailing slash for directories. It sometimes interferes with mod_rewrite. Just note that there are [possible security issues when turning it off](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).