# How do I make a subdomain redirect to a dedicated folder?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, cpanel

For example, how do I make test.domain.com redirect to Subomains/test or test2.domain.com redirect to Subdomains/test2 without changing the test.domain.com and without creating a subdomain in cPanel?

Could I make .htaccess get the subdomain and redirect it to the folder?

And when there's no folder named as the subdomain, it just redirects to domain.com

Comment: I think you could implement some 404 analysis. If visitor is searching condition 1, send him to X, if seeking 2, send him to Y.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to redirect via .htaccess. You can do this by changing the following code for your subdomain.

```
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
  
# Change subdomain.yourdomain.com to be your domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subdomain.)?yourdomain.com$
  
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
  
# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
  
# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subdomain.)?yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.html [L]
```

Please see: [.htaccess to make a subfolder the main folder for primary domain, but getting redundant redirects when URL is typed directly into browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524960/htaccess-to-make-a-subfolder-the-main-folder-for-primary-domain-but-getting-re)

Comment: I need for it to redirect to every subdomain entered, not just one. Is there a way to do that? Like subdomain is x and it opens Subdomains/x